# My code for Taylor series graphs cos(2x) instead of cos(x) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis, taylor-series

I'm writing a function that calculates the Taylor series of any Function.

```
syms  x
y=cos(x);
y0=0;
a=0;
for i=0:25
      diff(y,i);                                %%Gives the derivative formula
      y0=y0+diff(y,i)*((x-a)^i)/factorial(i);   %%sums every new element of the series
end

x=0:0.1:2*pi;
res = subs(y0,x);
plot(x,res,x,cos(x))
```

This is the Matlab code.

My problem is that it graphs `cos(2x)` instead of `cos(x)`, similarly it graphs `ln(2x)` instead of `ln(x)` and so on.

I have checked the factorials and they appear to be correct.
What could be the problem, have I messed up the series or have I made a Matlab mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing the Taylor polynomial around the point `x` with increment`x-a`, that is, you are computing an approximation for

```
f(x+(x-a))=f(2*x-a)
```

Now as `a=0`, this means that as observed, you get `f(2*x)`.

You would need to evaluate the derivatives at `a` to get the correct coefficients.

```
y0=y0+subs(diff(y,i),a)*((x-a)^i)/factorial(i);   %%sums every new element of the series
```

Comment: I have changed the code to be like this: 
`y=log(x);
y0=0;
a=0;

for i=0:30
    diff(y,i)
    y0=y0+diff(y,i)*((x-a)^i)/factorial(i);
end'`

It works fine for trigonometric Functions, but everything else is inverted. E.x log(x) gives a graph that approaches minus infinity, as x increases

Comment: As I said in the answer, you need to evaluate the derivatives at the expansion point. If you do not do this, then you get a wrong result. You can not use `a=0` as expansion point for the logarithm, as it has a singularity there. // A polynomial will always go to infinity if you increase its argument. If the highest degree coefficient is negative, that will be to negative infinity.